# using UIGestureRecognizer occur some problems

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, swift2

```
let recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
    for recognizer in self.gestureRecognizers! {
        if recognizer is DollarPGestureRecognizer {
            recognizer.recognize()
            self.clearAll()
        }
    }
```

how is ***if recognizer is DollarPGestureRecognizer*** means?
and also , recognize() function is declared in DollarPGesturRecognizer.h like

```
@interface DollarPGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer {
  DollarP *dollarP;
  NSMutableDictionary *currentTouches;
  NSMutableArray *currentPoints;
  NSMutableArray *points;
  int strokeId;
}
- (void)recognize;
@end
```

how can i successfully do the recognize function?

Answer (score 0):

Little unclear as to what you are asking but here goes:

**First Question Answer)** `recognizer is DollarPGestureRecognizer` returns `true` if recognizer is an instance of the  DollarPGestureRecognizer class.

**Second Question Answer)** In order to use the DollarPGestureRecognizer you need to instantiate an instance of one and then add is as a gesture recognizer to the view where you want it to be active. So you could do something like this (as a rough example):

```
let dollarRecognizer = DollarPGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"handleDollarGesture:"
myView.addGestureRecognizer(dollarRecognizer)
```

then define the handler in that target class (in this case self)

```
func handleDollarGesture(recognizer: DollarPGestureRecognizer) {
//Do Something
}
```

**Side Note)** If you want some help implementing your own custom UIGestureRecognizer you should look at the following article:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/104744/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-creating-custom-recognizers